# Rotational mechanics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

Is it possible that a disc is **rolling up** a rough inclined plane if only gravitational and frictional forces are acting on it ?
What I am confused about is,**which force is moving the disc up the plane** as gravitational force acts in downward direction and frictional​ force  can't be more than gravitational force here and no other force is acting.

Comment: Inertia? A body doesn't require a force to keep moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It will slow down it's rolling, but nevertheless roll uphill for a while.

The answer to your comment on the other answer is, that the friction direction **doesn't depend on rolling direction**! It *only* depends on other forces present. This is the case for static friction, which you have in pure rolling (the contact point doesn't slide but is static during the short touching duration).

When gravity pulls downwards, then friction must hold back in the contact point the opposite way to avoid sliding. Therefore, friction pulls upwards along the incline - both when the object rolls uphill and when it rolls downhill.

Answer (score 0):

Net force indicates acceleration, not velocity. If a disc is on an inclined plane with only gravitational, frictional, and the inherent normal force, the net force on it will be directed down the inclined plane. As Abhijeet Melkani commented, it can be moving up the inclined plane if it had an initial velocity in that direction. It will just be slowing down, and will eventually switch directions.

Comment: I understand that but I have to apply condition for pure rolling and I don't understand in which direction the friction will act, any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If there is no force, to begin with, or during the motion, then the disc will not be moving up at all. If there is no initial force, that implies no initial velocity and hence no initial kinetic energy. If there is no initial kinetic energy, the disc can't go up as it would violate conservation of energy law. Going up would imply it is gaining potential energy. That gain must occur at the expense of some other form of energy, which is absent here.
On the other hand, if there is a force, to begin with, the disc will go up for a while and then roll down.